# WebForms model binding insert stopped working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, model-binding

I am using webforms model binding on EF6 code first project.  I have a page that was working perfectly.  It stopped working with no apparent reason.  The insert method is not called anymore.  I have another insert page and it works perfectly still.  Anyone know of anything that would cause this?

Here is some of the markup that it is using.

```
 <asp:FormView runat="server" ID="fvTour"
        ItemType="CommonInterface.Tour" DefaultMode="Insert"
        InsertItemPosition="FirstItem" InsertMethod="InsertItem"
        OnItemCommand="ItemCommand" RenderOuterTable="false">
```

Code behind

```
public void InsertItem()
    {
        using (_db)
        {
            FileUpload picUpload = (FileUpload)fvTour.FindControl("fuploadTour");
            if (picUpload == null || !picUpload.HasFile) return;

            var item = new CommonInterface.Tour();

            item.MemberID = (int)Session["MemberID"];
            item.FID = LoginBLL.GetFID(item.MemberID);
            item.TourSubmitDate = DateTime.Now;
            item.PID = null;
            item.TourState = ((DropDownList)fvTour.FindControl("ddlState")).SelectedItem.Text;
            item.TourCounty = ((DropDownList)fvTour.FindControl("ddlCounties")).SelectedItem.Text;
            item.TourLayout = ((DropDownList)fvTour.FindControl("ddlLayout")).SelectedItem.Text;
            item.TourType = ((DropDownList)fvTour.FindControl("ddlType")).SelectedItem.Text;



            TryUpdateModel(item);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Save changes
                _db.Tours.Add(item);
                _db.SaveChanges();

                Response.Redirect("Default");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit 2:
Try to use `OnItemCommand` and see if that works. Set `OnItemCommand="ItemCommand"` back to your markup and try the following on code behind:

```
public void ItemCommand(object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Insert")
    {
        InsertItem();
    }
}
```

Make sure that the button you press has a `CommandName="Insert"` attribute set.
You should be able to set a breakpoint on this method at least. Then you can see if the button fires an event at all.

Comment: Even when I remove the OnItemCommand the InsertItem method is still not firing anymore.  I also tried adding simple code of setting an integer and then changing the value and I get the warning that the variable is initialized, but not used.

Comment: Since it's a form view you propably use a template? Is the insert button properly set to be an _insert_ button, ie. does the formview know that insert command is bound with that button?

Comment: Yeah the page is actually a proof of concept using webforms model binding that I was going to move to a DTO.  It worked perfectly for a week or two and then quit working.  The button still calls the item command and the dropdowns on the page still work.  The other part is I can't write manual code that will call the insert method.  I can not make a breakpoint hit it no matter what I try.

Comment: I reinstalled Visual Studio and something different.  I can hit the breakpoint now, but the validation is not working anymore.  The commandname was actually submit and item command was working but I moved it to insert as well.  Thanks for the help so far.  Any ideas to get the validation to work again?  Worst case I will just put custom validators so not a really bid deal.